# Can GetFileAttributesExA return stale information on an SMB3 mount?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, filesystems, smb

I'm trying to figure the root cause of an issue in a single-threaded Python program that essentially goes like this (heavily simplified):

```py
# Before running
os.remove(path)

# While running
if os.path.isfile(path):
    with open(path) as fd:
        ...
```

I'm essentially seeing erratic behavior where `isfile` (which uses `stat`, itself using `GetFileAttributesExA` under the hood in Python 2.7, see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#L1151)) can return `True` when the file doesn't exist, failing the next `open` call.

`path` being on an SMB3 network share, I'm suspecting caching behavior of some kind. Is it possible that `GetFileAttributesExA` returns stale information?

Reducing SMB client caching from the default (10s) to 0s seems to make the issue disappear:

```bsh
Set-SmbClientConfiguration -DirectoryCacheLifetime 0 -FileInfoCacheLifetime 0
```

*(Note: The correct fix here is to `try` opening the file and catch the exception, of course, but I'm puzzled by the issue and would like to understand the root cause.)*

Comment: Quite the anti-pattern there: Check for file existence and then try to open the file. The suggested procedure would be: Open the file. You have to handle errors anyway, so why introduce a race condition that doesn't help you in any way?

Comment: Sure, see the note at the bottom. I'm trying to debug an existing code that I didn't write, and getting puzzled by this behavior that I find counter-intuitive compared to what I'm used for on other platforms, especially given the fact that the program is single-threaded, and as such should not be subject to race conditions on its own.

Comment: Still stuck on 2.7 for some of our tools unfortunately, see the [win32_stat](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#L1151) function. I intentially framed the question in a more general way because I was curious about caching behavior in Windows APIs. Edited the question!

Comment: The `FileInfoCacheLifetime` setting is discussed in [SMB2 Client Redirector Caches Explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ff686200(v=ws.10)).

Comment: *"the program is single-threaded, and as such should not be subject to race conditions"* - Whenever a program accesses external resources, it is instantly subject to race conditions with any other programs racing for those resources.

Comment: `GetFileAttributesEx` is implemented via `NtQueryFullAttributesFile`, which the I/O manager implements as a query-only open of the path, which uses a dummy File object to query the `FileNetworkOpenInformation`. This contrasts with the slow path that uses `NtOpenFile` (or `NtCreateFile`) and `NtQueryInformationFile`. Bypassing the file open is why the client-side cached info is used even though the file doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: `os.stat` in Python 3 calls `CreateFileW` (which calls `NtCreateFile`), and the File handle is used to query file information via `GetFileInformationByHandle` (i.e. `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` and `NtQueryInformationFile`). So I expect 3.x `os.stat` fails with a `FileNotFoundError` in this case due to `CreateFileW` failing with `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: @ErykSun Thank you, that's exactly the info I needed. Do you have a source for that the different behaviors of `NtQueryFullAttributesFile` and `NtCreateFile` that I could accept as an answer?

Comment: @ErykSun Also, I suppose that the SMB2 Client Cache docs are actually valid for SMB2 and SMB3? I couldn't find info on whether that was true, but at the same time the setting had an effect ;)

Comment: The internal implementation of the I/O manager is not documented by Microsoft. But you can see in ReactOS, which is reverse engineered to behave like Windows Server 2003, how the internal function [`IopQueryAttributesFile`](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/a7b111f5503e216bbcbb3c0070c2ff2fa112aa34/ntoskrnl/io/iomgr/file.c#L2341) creates a `QueryOnly` open packet. This leads to the use of a dummy File object in the Device object's parse routine, `IopParseDevice`. (In the case of a UNC path, it's the Multiple UNC Provider device, opening a native path like "\Device\Mup\server\share\file".)

Comment: The slow way to query `FileNetworkOpenInformation` starts by opening the file via `NtCreateFile` or `NtOpenFile`, which eventually parses up to the Device object and calls `IopParseDevice`, which sends an `IRP_MJ_CREATE` request to the device stack, to open the file with a real File object and return a handle to it. This step will fail if the file doesn't exist on the server. Otherwise than handle is passed to `NtQueryInformationFile`: `FileNetworkOpenInformation`. But normally this would actually be `FileAllInformation`, as is requested by WINAPI `GetFileInformationByHandle`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details, that pointed me to the right direction, somewhat. Would I be correct in assuming that this behavior corresponds to the use of [Fast I/O](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/irps-are-different-from-fast-i-o) operations in case of `QueryOnly` packets? That would explain a lot (and the driver docs clearly state that it should be getting cached data if available). Also, [this link](https://www.osronline.com/article.cfm%5Eid=166.htm) has a lot of info on caching, most of which goes way over my head (and also an expired cert, but oh well).